@Autowired component Null
I don't know why, but my @Autowired component (jwtService) returns a NullPointerException.
Here is my code:
This is my JwtTokenValidator class:
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class JwtTokenValidator extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtService jwtService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
                                    @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
                                    @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        String token = authHeader.substring(7);

        try {
            String email = jwtService.extractEmail(token);

            String authorities = jwtService.extractAuthorities(token);

            List<GrantedAuthority> auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(authorities);

            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, null, auth);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

and this is my JwtService class:
@Service
public class JwtService {

    private SecretKey key =  Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(JwtConstant.SECRET_KEY.getBytes());

    public String extractEmail(String token) {
        return String.valueOf(extractAllClaims(token).get("email"));
    }

    public String extractAuthorities(String token) {
        return String.valueOf(extractAllClaims(token).get("authorities"));
    }


    public Claims extractAllClaims(String token){

        return Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(key)
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication){

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();

        String roles = populateAuthorities(authorities);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)))
                .claim("email", authentication.getName())
                .claim("authorities", roles)
                .signWith(key, SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

    public String populateAuthorities(Collection <? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities){

        Set<String> auths = new HashSet<>();

        for(GrantedAuthority authority : authorities){
            auths.add(authority.getAuthority());
        }
        return String.join(",",auths);
    }

}


I got this error message:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.Abdelouadoud.MoroccoCraftsAPI.config.JwtService.extractEmail(String)" because "this.jwtService" is null
    at com.Abdelouadoud.MoroccoCraftsAPI.config.JwtTokenValidator.doFilterInternal(JwtTokenValidator.java:55) ~[classes/:na]

I verified that JwtService is a bean (it contains a @Service annotation).
I also verified that I had never initiated JwtService manually in the other classes.
I really need your help, thank you!

It's funny how I searched the problem for a day long, and then I find the solution minutes after posting my question.
In fact I realized that I was initiating the JwtTokenValidator manually.
Once I replaced it with an Autowired component, the problem was solved.
